# Pointing to a Matrix

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix

I wanted to declare a pointer which would point to a matrix and retrieve a value back from the matrix:

```
float *p;
float ar[3][3];

[..]//give values to ar[][]

p = ar;

//Keep on printing values in the 3 X 3 matrix
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
p = p + i;
cout << *p << ", ";
}
```

Comment: If I should use **p to point to the matrix ar[][], and how can I get the value of the pointer which is pointing to a specific element in the matrix.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that you are after:

```
p = &ar[0][0];
```

which can also be written:

```
p = ar[0];
```

although your `for` loop then needs to use `p = p + 1;` rather than `p = p + i;`.

---

You can also use a pointer to an array, if you want your loop to be able to access the members of the matrix by row and column:

```
float (*p)[3];

p = ar;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        cout << p[i][j] << ", ";
    }
```

Comment: what if I wanted to use a double pointer to point at the matrix and de-reference values from the matrix?

Comment: @Josh: You must clarify what you mean by a "double pointer".  If you mean a `double *` (pointer to double), then you can't, because the matrix stores `float` values.  If you mean a `float **` (pointer to pointer to float), then the only way to do that is to create a shadow array of `float *` values, pointing at the first `float` in each row of the matrix.  Perhaps you want a pointer to an array (`float (*)[3]`) (see update)?

Comment: I wanted to use "**p" to point to some elements in ar[][] and retrieve those elements (to find the determinant of the matrix), so can I do this: **p; p = ar; value += **(p + 1);

Comment: @Josh: You can't really do that, because `float **p` isn't the right tool for that job.  A `float **p` variable is for pointing at a `float *` (or an array of `float *`), and you don't *have* any `float *` objects in your example.  You could create some, but there's no point, it would just be needlessly obfuscatory.

Comment: @Josh: You can iterate through the matrix using the pointer `p` in my first example, but you only have to dereference it once (`*(p + i)` or `p[i]` for `i` in 0..9).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT2**: I'm an idiot I accidentally had `float **matrix` instead of `float (*matrix)[3]`. caf had the right answer all along.

Is this what you want?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_matrix(float (*matrix)[3], size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
         printf("%f ", matrix[i][j]);
}

int main(void)
{
   float ar[][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };
   print_matrix(ar, 3, 3);

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**EDIT:** you can also have:

```
float *row1, *row2, *row3;
row1 = ar[0];
row2 = ar[1];
row3 = ar[2];
...
float row1_total = row1[0] + row1[1] + row2[2];
```

Comment: I wanted to use a pointer to access the matrix elements. Instead of printing using the matrix itself, I wanted a pointer to access the elements in the matrix and perform some operations using them (like addition)

Comment: `float **matrix` is a pointer (to a pointer to a float). You can access the elements using pointer arithmetic or array notation as I did.

Comment: so if I wanted to access the value stored in ar[1][1], I would do **(matrix + 4)?

Comment: It would be better to do it as `matrix[1][1]`, especially if each of the "rows" in the matrix weren't in consecutive blocks of memory. You gain no advantage by doing `**(matrix + 4)`, only reducing readability and potentially causing problems.

Comment: You would have to use `void print_matrix(float matrix[][3], size_t rows, size_t cols)`, or `void print_matrix(float *matrix[3], size_t rows, size_t cols)`, I think.  As written, the function doesn't know how wide each row is.

Comment: The amount of columns (`size_t cols`) specifies how wide each row is.

Comment: Did you even try this? It does not work; you cannot pass a `float (*)[3]` to a function expecting a `float **`.

Comment: @caf I'm an idiot, `float **matrix` was meant to be `float (*matrix)[3]`, which I now see that you posted. This is the only answer that I haven't compiled. :\ +1